# Proving that: $e^{-x(1/\tau - i\xi)} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

I remember my friend showing me how sandwich theorem can be applied here. Unfortunately, I can't find his solution anymore and I am not familiar with sandwich theory.

Comment: What are $\tau$ and $\xi$? Real constants, positive real constants?

Comment: yes, sorry, positive real constants

Comment: Is it $\frac{1}{\tau} - i\xi$ or $\frac{1}{\tau - i\xi}$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\tau}-i\xi \equiv \frac{1-i\xi \tau}{\tau}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $\tau>0$ and $x,\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. Then using $\left|e^{-ia}\right|=1 $ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we get
$$
0<\left|e^{-x(1/\tau - i\xi)}\right|=\left|e^{-x/\tau}\right|\times \underbrace{\left|e^{ ix\xi}\right|}_{\color{red}{=1}}\leq e^{-x/\tau}
$$ giving
$$
0\leq\lim_{x \to \infty}\left|e^{-x(1/\tau - i\xi)}\right|\leq \lim_{x \to \infty}e^{-x/\tau}=0.
$$

Comment: that first line, how come: $|e^{-x(1/\tau - i\xi)}| = |e^{-x/\tau}|*|e^{ix\xi}|$, in the sense that the modulus of a complex number is the product of its parts, is this a property of a modulus?

Comment: oh wait, it is an absolute value multiplied by a modulus..

Comment: I just have one conceptual hurdle, namely we have analyzed the modulus of this complex exponential, would this result apply then to just the value $e^{-x(1/\tau-i\xi)}$?

Comment: You have, for all complex numbers, $|z_1 \times z_2|=|z_1| \times |z_2|$. Thus, we have $\left|e^{-x(1/\tau - i\xi)}\right|=\left|e^{-x/\tau} \times e^{i x \xi}\right|=\left|e^{-x/\tau}\right|\times \left|e^{ ix\xi}\right|=e^{-x/\tau}\times 1=e^{-x/\tau}$.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that. My complex analysis knowledge is pretty much non existent